# jpa oneToMany and jackson serialization problems (newbie)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I don't know very well how to entitle this question, so feel free to edit it if needed.

I'm kind of new to jpa/spring and i'm finding a problem that i think it should be very common but i couldn't find any reasonable answer for it.

I'm creating a RestAPI with springboot. This API has 2 endpoints  **(GET) /user** and **(GET) /address** which maps 1:1 to entities in my DB. The relation between them is 1:N, joining by the user_id.

The idea i have in mind is that depending on which endpoint is called, return the entity completely filled (the user with his addresses or a list of addresses with the user filled).

I have tried to use **jpa annotations OneToMany/ManyToOne** so hibernate resolves this automatically, but in that case i need to annotate also the fields with Jackson annotations which are static and will break one of my endpoints. (i can get the user with the addresses, or the addresses with the user, but not both)

The option b) i found is to break the relation and leave in the entity the ids and set the full object as transient being filled afterwards in code. For the manyToOne relation is easy to do the mapping, but not that much for the OneToMany as i have to get all the addresses, all the users and do the mapping by code. I expect to have a big amount of user and addresses so this can be expensive.

Another possible solutions for this, but i haven't found how to do it is be able to limit the recursion to 1 level when serializing to json in the controller, but i didn't see how to do it.

Also it could be done by being able to fill with a custom jql/sql query a transient field with a standar join.

For the example given let's imagine the tables looks like this:

```
User:
 - id: long autoincrement (PK)
 - name: varchar(255)

Address:
 - id long autoincrement (PK)
 - user_id long,
 - street varchar(255)
```

Thanks a lot and sorry for the big text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a way to achieve this in a not so dirty way.

I created an interface for each instance without the methods that will create a cycle reference making the Jackson serialization class.

with the @JsonSerialize(as=MyInterface.class) on the attribute of the entity which will make it recursive (address in user, and user in address)

In this way meanwhile you keep 1 depth level in the json, you can achieve a "dynamic" serialization of your classes